# Next.js equivalent of NuxtPage to to use in parent page

Tags: next.js, nuxt.js, dynamic-routing

How to display child (page) route inside parent (page) route in `Next.js` like `Nuxt.js` (using `NuxtPage` component). To avoid repetition of code.

In `Nuxt.js` I need not to check whether child route is valid or not, if page exists (defined) for current path then it will render that page else `Page not found`. But in `Next.js` I have to manually check `router.query` whether It follows the desired route pattern or not.

As I can't use `outlet (react router)` in Next, is there any way to achieve below Nuxt.js thing in Next.js.

#### In Nuxt.js

```
-| pages/
---| [username]/
------| stats.vue
------| settings.vue
------| about.vue
---| [username].vue
---| index.vue
```

`/@johndoe123`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> User </h1>
    <NuxtPage :foobar="123" />
  </div>
</template>
```

#### In Next.js I tried this

This cause repetition of code as having same layout with some different content.

```
-| pages/
---| [username] / 
------| index.tsx
------| stats.tsx
------| settings.tsx
------| about.tsx
---| index.tsx
```

Or I can `catch-all`, then I have to varify slug value.

```
-| pages/
---| [username]/
------[[...slug]].tsx
---| index.tsx
```